# Should crown molding go over stone fireplace?

Tags: ceiling, fireplace, mounting, trim, design

I understand this is somewhat (design) subjective, but I have no reference to what is common practice when it comes to this type of application. 
I'm going to be running (foam) crown molding with LED lighting around the top of the room, a couple of inches off the ceiling for the light, but the fireplace is in the corner. I was thinking I would just go over the top of it, but... now I'm not sure.

I've seen it without the LED lighting, but with lighting like that, should the molding go over stone?

[image: picture]

Comment: Personally,  I'd stop the crown molding at each end of the fireplace with some compound miter end caps unless you're really good with a coping saw. If you run it a couple inches off the ceiling , your recessed lights will leave a shadow at the top of the fireplace.  Just my humble opinion.

Comment: Jack that should be an answer, it would be difficult to anchor the bottom of the crown molding on the stone work, but there is usually a small piece of trim.

Comment: @JACK Good point about the recessed lighting... I'll need to think about that a bit more. Thanks.

Comment: I agree with JACK, and I'd add that most stonework like this is intended to create the illusion that the chimney extends past (through) the ceiling and out the roof, like it would have were this a true conventional fireplace. Crown would destroy that illusion.

Comment: I had another thought... what if i took a small 1/2" x 5" piece of pine or flat baseboard and put it across the top, then affix the molding to that, essentially still making it 'look' like it's going through the ceiling and you wouldn't see the stone then at the top.
I know I still have the can lights to contend with, but I may be changing those up. 

Curious about thoughts doing a connecting piece like that...

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'd stop the crown molding at each end of the fireplace with some compound miter end caps unless you're really good with a coping saw. If you run it a couple inches off the ceiling , your recessed lights will leave a shadow at the top of the fireplace. Just my humble opinion.